# seleccionar un boton entre varios, android studio

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment

tengo un layout con 30 botones modificados para que solo parezcan textos y al momento de hacer clic en uno de ellos éste haga una llamada a un numero de teléfono pre asignado.

El problema que tengo es que no estoy pudiendo hacer que dicho botón tome el evento clic para poder hacer el llamado.

A continuación les comparto el codigo de layout (resumido) y el fragment en la parte que no puedo hacer que funcione. Desde ya muchas gracias por su tiempo.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/category"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:text="Lineas Rotativas"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#AEEA00"
    android:textSize="21sp" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/telefono"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:maxHeight="35dp"
    android:maxWidth="74dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />

<!--///////////////////////////////////////////// 1-->

<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Banda Municipal"
    android:id="@+id/category1"
    android:textSize="21sp"
    android:textColor="#AEEA00"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="2dp"

    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:cropToPadding="false"
    android:src="@drawable/telefono"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"

    android:maxHeight="35dp"
    android:maxWidth="74dp"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="55dp"
   />
   </RelativeLayout>
  </ScrollView>
```

Esta es la parte del Fragment en la que no estoy pudiendo hacer que  si

```
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
final View dialoglayout = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_telefonosutiles,null);

Button btn_lineas_rotativas = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.category);
Button btn_banda_municipal =  (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.category1);
Button btn_bibloteca = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.category2);
Button btn_bromatologia = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.category3);




public void onClick(View v) {
  // TextView id = v (R.id.texto);


    if (btn_lineas_rotativas.callOnClick()){
        Log.e("titulo", "onbuttonPressed");
        String phoneNo ="59177302270";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo)) {
            String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(dial)));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Buenas @Luis, consulta no estarían faltando las asignaciones de los botones al setOnClickListener?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al obtener la referencia del botón puedes asignarle un listener (`OnClickListener`) de esta forma funcionaría correctamente:

```
Button btn_lineas_rotativas = (Button) dialoglayout.findViewById(R.id.category);
...
...

btn_lineas_rotativas.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {


        Log.e("titulo", "onbuttonPressed");
        String phoneNo ="59177302270";
        if (!TextUtils.isEmpty(phoneNo)) {
            String dial = "tel:" + phoneNo;
            this.startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.parse(dial)));
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(), "Enter a phone number", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }


    }
});
```